# Impact of payment plan loans on credit score

Tags: united-states, credit-score, micropayment

Many online payment networks now allow instant installment plans for small retail purchases. Normally, the purchase would be a one time payment. These products transparently convert it to a payment plan, often without interest.

For example, [PayPal has a service](https://www.paypal.com/us/digital-wallet/ways-to-pay/buy-now-pay-later) where instead of say, paying $60 for a pair of shoes, you can pay 4 installments of $15. This is implemented as a loan, so they ask for SSN, your credit history etc.

Does routinely using such services negatively impact your credit score?

Answer (score 2):

It may. It will affect the credit utilization, account age, total debt, etc - all factors in determining the score.

It will also affect your record of on-time payments and paying off loans, which are positive signals.

Comment: Wouldn't the effects be minimal, because these payments are so small?

Comment: @gomennathan may be. Maybe not. Depends on variety of factors which change from model to model

Comment: @gomennathan I imagine that if/when use of such services grows, credit scores will take them into account more, even if the (individual) amounts are small.

Comment: @TripeHound Interesting. I was more asking about the situation *now*.